# Angular4 app not working in Edge and IE Browser

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cross-browser, microsoft-edge

Working on an Angular4 app using Edge browser(version 15) and it doesn't get past the 1st screen - keep loading and returns to 1st screen.
Have looked online for a fix and tried amending the target, lib and disabling SourceMap in the  tsconfig.json but to no avail.

tsconfig.json:-

```
{
  "compilerOptions":
   {
   "target": "es5",
   "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
   "module": "commonjs",
   "moduleResolution": "node",
          //"sourceMap": true,
         // "inlineSourceMap": true,
   "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
   "experimentalDecorators": true,
   "removeComments": false,
   "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
   "rootDir": "ClientApp",
   "types": [ "core-js" ]
  },

}
```

Any suggestions appreciated...attached screenshot of error

[image]

Thanks
Maiur

Comment: Did you install platform-browser-dynamic?

Comment: @pixelbits Yes platform-browser-dynamic is installed

Comment: If you're on a corporate network and there's a proxy server then make sure the rules allow requests to `localhost` to bypass the proxy. Also check Windows firewall rules permit access to that port though if it works in other browsers that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: @Duncan it works prefectly in Chrome - proxy server is set to automatically detect settings and the 1st page loads fine in Edge its when you click next that the error occurs.

Comment: Seems the issue is with router.navigate as when I enter the address in the browser the component loads...still investigating why this won't work for edge...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enabling IE polyfills? If you go to the file polyfills.ts you will see a lot of them commented out by default and you just need to uncomment them and rebuild your app.

Answer (score 0):

Its because some of the HTML tags are not supported by edge.In my case it was window.location.href , changed that to document.URL worked in edge after that